# Blank product review page

Tags: review

Hi I'm fairly new to Magento so this might be a stupid question.

I'm using default/carparts theme for my website. The problem is that the product reviews page is always blank like this:

[image]

Previous reviews and review form are not showing.
I believe this is a bug of this theme because I tried other themes and this page all works well. 
Could somebody tell me what files should I check to fix this?

Comment: Enable path hind and check all files are rendered

Answer (score 1):

Replace `default/carparts/layout/review.xml` file. You can get fresh file from `rwd/default/layout/review.xml`

This file is responsible for your review.

Se section: `<review_product_list translate="label">`. Make sure this section exist in your `review.xml` file.

Please make backup of that file before replacing.

Answer (score 1):

product/view.phtml was missing:

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi zxwang and welcome to MageOverflow. Unfortunately we can't help with all third party issues.You should read [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) and I recommend to set an exception breakpoint for xdebug. Often an exception is thrown which is then catched and ignored.

```
    try {
        $viewHelper->prepareAndRender($productId, $this, $params);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == $viewHelper->ERR_NO_PRODUCT_LOADED) {
            if (isset($_GET['store'])  && !$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                $this->_redirect('');
            } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                $this->_forward('noRoute');
            }
        } else {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_forward('noRoute');
        }
    }
```

This leads to an 404 status, but shows the page